# Definition of a primitive representation

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, terminology

In this [paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/81202456.pdf), a representation $\pi: G \to \operatorname{GL}(V)$  is said to be primitive if

1. $\pi$ is irreducible and
2. there exists no decomposition of $V$ as the direct sum of proper non-zero subspaces permuted by G.

Could you please describe what 2. technically means? It would be helpful if you could write the condition as a formula. Right now, this just sounds like 1. where there is no proper non-zero subspace which is invariant under $G$. I thought being permuted by $G$ and being invariant under $G$ is the same.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Consider the group of two by two matrices of the forms
$$\pmatrix{a&0\\0&b}$$
and
$$\pmatrix{0&a\\b&0}$$
for $ab\ne0$. Suppose the image of $\rho$ is this group.
Then $\rho$ is irreducible, but is not primitive. The vector
subspaces of the forms $\pmatrix{*\\0}$ and $\pmatrix{0\\*}$ form
a direct sum composition of $K^2$ but are permuted by $G$.

Comment: Could you please explain too what "permuted by $G$ means?

Comment: You have subspaces $V_1$ and $V_2$: a group element of the first term preserves each, of the second kind, swaps them.

Comment: I assume this is the explanation for the example. Let $V_1=\langle\begin{pmatrix}* // 0\end{pmatrix}\rangle$ and $V_2=\langle\begin{pmatrix}* // 0\end{pmatrix}\rangle$. For the group action $\varphi:G=\langle A_1=\begin{pmatrix}a & 0\\ 0 & b \end{pmatrix}, A_2=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & a\\ b & 0 \end{pmatrix}\rangle\times V=V_1\oplus V_2\to V_1\oplus V_2$, $(g,v)\mapsto\rho_g(v)$, we get $A_1(V_1)=V_1$ and $A_1(V_2)=V_2$ and $A_2(V_1)=V_2$ and $A_2(V_2)=V_1$. So does "primitive" mean that for any decomposition of $V=\bigoplus V_i$, we have $\varphi(x) \in V_i,V_j$ for some $x\in V$ and $i \neq j$?

Comment: @Diglett Primitive means, roughly speaking, that there's no decomposition like this.